# PHP includes not allowing stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, include, stylesheet

I have just a basic website and I haven't run into this problem except when I am trying to use php includes for certain parts of my website. I am just learning how to use this and I do not understand why these end tags are being highlighted. I have the file saved as php, it on my xampp and everything is closed. Is the php includes statement not written correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css"/>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'includes/header.php';?>

    <?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my header.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<header>
                <p>Hello World</p>
              </header>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my stylesheet also. All this is very basic and I just am not understanding why if I don't use php includes it works and the stylesheet is imported but it I use the includes it wont import the stylesheet correctly and it says i have invalid closings on the `</body> </html>` on the index.php

Comment: Your header.php should only be  the content within and including the `<header>` tag. As you already have a `<html>` tag open.

Comment: You can't redeclare your doctype and head again in an included file.

Comment: The include inserts the file exactly where the include statement occurs, so You've got multiple <head> tags includinging one inside the body.

Comment: include basically puts all the code you have in the file into the destination, so your header.php would only be `<header><p>Hello World</p></header>`

Comment: Sweet this worked! thank you I didnt realize that it was reading all the other stuff for html in the header.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `header.php` should not have `body` tags anymore.
These are already set in your main file.

`header.php` should look like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<header>
            <p>Hello World</p>
          </header>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what happens when you "include" your file. If you just copy the contents of the included file you can see what it's doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css"/>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<header>
                <p>Hello World</p>
              </header>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>

    <?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

Does that look like a valid HTML page to you? It's not. Your header.php should look like this:

```
<header>
    Hello World
</header>
```

That's it, you don't need the PHP opening tag, or the echo or any of the rest (note the lack of paragraph tags as well, you shouldn't include them in a header). If you want to put a PHP variable in it then you can do this:

```
<header>
    <?= $myVarContainingHtml ?>
</header>
```

`<?=` is short for `<?php echo`

Answer (score 0):

YOu don't need all the the HTML in your header.php. Basically it should just be:

```
<?php echo "<header>
<p>Hello World</p>
</header>";
```

by adding all the rest of the html document you are including a full HTML document within a HTML document which will break the page.